# 14.04: Unable to locate package mesa

Tags: 14.04, apt, fglrx, mesa

`sudo apt-get install mesa` results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mesa
```

---

```
lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Device 3221
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

Comment: What are you trying to install? There is no such package.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've had problems with my fps in Dota 2 and I've been told the mesa package should help that out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2` terminal command there.

Comment: You have already installed a proprietary AMD driver. There is nothing else to be done.

Comment: @Pilot6 Oh, ok. The performance is just terrible, there isn't anything more to do in terms of tweaking out more fps?

Right now, I'm running 20-30 fps in Dota 2 whereas in Windows 7, it's stable 120 :(

Comment: Maybe to install Ubuntu 15.04. There is a new fglrx driver. I am not sure it will install on 14.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 sorry for the noob question here: does installing a new ubuntu version wipe out everything? Will I keep all my apps and setup etc? If so, I guess i'll try that?

Comment: If you do a fresh install, you will need to re-install applications. You can ask another question abut that, or search for solutions.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=mesa